# parsing text file in pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, rdd

i am trying to convert the below text file to a hive table using pyspark.

so my text file looks like the below

```
nethandle: 129
orgid: csu
netname: east

nethandle: 908
orgid: dmo
netname: west

nethandle: 987
orgid: csu
netname: west
```

my code is the below

```
lines=sc.textFile("/tmp/sample/sam.txt")
parts=lines.flatMap(lambda l:tuple(l.split(""))
for j in parts.collect():
    print(j)
```

but the result i am getting the same as input. But i am expecting something like this

```
[129,csu,east]
[908,dmo,west]
[987,csu,east]
```

could u plz help me in this.i am not sure how to use lambda function...thanks in advance.

Comment: You won't be able to process this file using the `.textFile` features because that automatically splits the file at each newLine and could send each line to a different node in your cluster. Are you planning to process a single huge file or many small files?

Comment: a single huge file with millions of rows like this @soundstripe

Answer (score 0):

OK so here's an idea that may work. Pyspark offers a `.zipWithIndex()` function that is like python's built-in `enumerate`. You could use this to add an index to each row, and then since each record is 4 lines (including a blank line) you could take the mod-4 of each index and make that the record key. `aggregateByKey()` should let you group those.

Something like this (I don't have spark installed and can't test this right now):

```
sc = pyspark.SparkContext()
lines = sc.textFile("/tmp/sample/sam.txt")
parts = lines.zipWithIndex() \
    .map(lambda row: (row[0] % 4, row[1].split(": ")[-1])) \
    .aggregateByKey([], lambda a, b: a + [b], lambda a, b: a + b)
print(parts.collect())
```

I'm going to show the same code again, without using lambda, to help you see how to write lambdas:

```
def add_key_and_split_line(index, line):
    key = index % 4
    value = line.split(": ")[-1]
    return key, value

def join_list_to_val(a, b):
    return a + [b]

def join_list_to_list(a, b):
    return a + b

sc = pyspark.SparkContext()
lines = sc.textFile("/tmp/sample/sam.txt")
parts = lines.zipWithIndex() \
    .map(add_key_and_split_line) \
    .aggregateByKey([], join_list_to_val, join_list_to_list)
print(parts.collect())
```

Comment: Thanks ...good idea over thr...i am following ur code . Getting "type error: lambda takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given )"..not sure which lambda

Comment: I made an edit with a guess as to which lambda was broken -- Unfortunately to be sure I'll need more information.

Comment: Hi,..I ran your code in different ways to find out where the problem is .
1) parts = lines.zipWithIndex().map(lambda i, l: (i%4, l.split(": ")[-1])).aggregateByKey([], lambda a, b: a + [b], lambda a, b:a + b)
(result: TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given))
2) ran the query using definitions without lambda.
(result: TypeError: add_key_and_split_line() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given))

Comment: 3) splitted the lambda functions into seperate parts.
parts_1 = map(parts, lambda i, l: (i%4, l.split(": ")[-1]))
(result: TypeError: argument 2 to map() must support iteration
) --> so finalized that the error is from this part of the lambda function.
4) tried like this..
 parts_1 = map( lambda i, l: (i%4, l.split(": ")),parts[-1])
(result: TypeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object does not support indexing)